# Why can the President campaign for a candidate?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

Why is the President allowed to campaign for a candidate?  Are there any restrictions to this?

Comment: Are there any laws restricting any citizen from campaigning?

Comment: Why do you think they shouldn't? There's no requirement, or even implication, of neutrality in the role.

Comment: Because it's a free country.

Comment: @Alex - one can argue that he's using the power of the office to promote a specific party. That is philosophically not necessarily OK - and in practice, it's illegal to use taxpayer funds to campaign.

Comment: @Jalynn - Yes there are.  Though every time someone challenges the law they end up overturned

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is there is nothing that prevents the incumbent President from campaigning.

You should note that President Obama and Vice President Biden are elected officials. In this sense, they are different from other government employees who are not elected.

There are no federal laws that prevent them from campaigning for other candidates they endorse. However, if they use the government resources such as Air Force One, the expense calculated in accordance with relevant law should be reimbursed by the campaign.

Answer (score 2):

Because free political thought and speech is a cherished and protected right in the US.  Regardless of how corrupted the government has become the founders realized that there was always a chance to right the ship as long as the people can talk about the realities of the people running the government.

This extends to every person in the country including the president.

When using government Facilities for election events the venue must be made available to all candidates for use at comparable times.  So say Obama decided to do a speech in support of Hillary from the oval Office tonight then They would have to make accommodations for all of the candidates who wish to use the Oval Office during a comparable time slot. So the blanket rule is no campaigning in places that are not open for public gatherings anyway.

Comment: Just know they can't use taxpayer money to do it.  And they can't do it from public facilities.  One reason you won't see a campaign speech from the Rose Garden.

Comment: Agreed Dep.  Your's is better stated

Comment: It should be noted a speech about a contested issue isn't necessarily a campaign speech, while possibly having an effect on a campaign.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - It does not really matter.  Its all protected speech.

Comment: @DeplorableNumber9035768 Just a nitpick. Since you say an official has to pay for the use and make available common resources when campaigning I thought the loop hole might be relevant. Our officials may be slightly less restricted then the picture you present. And while I'm picking would it compromise your integrity to tone down the corruption line?

Comment: @Dep But there may be differences re: use of official government resources. For instance, if Obama wants to promote the TPP, that's something government resources can legitimately be spent on. If Obama wants to promote Hillary Clinton, that's not a legitimate use of government funds.

Comment: @Cpast yes.  But during an election phase the president is not going to make a speech from an area they are not willing to have opened up to all candidates just for that reason.  The caution is to err to the side of yes it would open it up unless there is a compelling reason why the speech should be given from the oval office or somewhere else not typically open.  That said there are a number of halls near or in the white house that are generic looking halls that are available already that suit the purpose for most speeches.

Comment: If the president were to make a speech to the nation from the oval office this week about TPP, and decide to go off on a tangent and talk about how trump wants to kill the treaty. they would have to open the oval office up to all the candidate.  Not just Hilary and Donald either.  Gary Johnson, Jill Stein, and all the others.

Comment: @Dep For practical reasons near the election, you're definitely right. I was thinking more about between elections: if Obama had been giving a speech about TPP in late 2015 and had flown Air Force One to LA to do it, he wouldn't be expected to reimburse any of the costs. Similarly, a civil servant in the US Trade Representative's office can write material on the clock saying why TPP is good, while they can't write pro-Clinton material on the clock.